# Can see MOSS 2007 image as admin, but not as user - cannot figure out

Tags: 2007

I'm hoping someone can help me figure this out. First, to help you understand what we use here, we have MOSS 2007. We have three different site collections set up. From each site collection, I create sites and sub-sites. A mock-up of the path would be:

//site-collectionsp.com/site/sub-site

I'm having problems getting the logo to display for people who have access only to the sub-site and not to the site collection nor upper-level site. For this particular issue, the path of this sub-site is (all paths in this message - except links to images - are mock-ups and not real):

//site-collectionsp.com/site/sub-site

I created a logo and and, using SP Designer, placed the logo onto the sub-site's server. The URL would be:

//site-collectionsp.com/site/sub-site/test-logo.jpg

I closed Designer and typed the full URL in the browser window, copied it, then, under title, description, and icon, I placed the direct URL for the logo URL.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Since I am the admin, I went to the sub-site and the logo displays like it should. See image below:

[image: Screenshot 2]

I logged out and then logged into the site as someone else (Lisa). This other person ONLY has access to the sub-site and not the site-collection nor site. When I logged in as her, the logo does not display. See image below:

[image: Screenshot 3]

So I then went back into Designer. I opened up the master page and looked at the code; I'm looking at the path of the logo and for some odd reason, there is some other logo, a GIF image, as the logo and not the one I placed on the server. See image below:

[image: Screenshot 4]

Furthermore, in Designer, I cannot see the _layouts folder on the server (maybe because I am do not have top admin rights; I'm not sure why). So as a work-around to see if I can get this logo to appear for Lisa, I made a duplicate of the master page. I named it default2.master, opened it up in Designer, and looked at the logo code.

Because the logo is already on the server, with the path being "https://site-collectionsp.com/site/sub-site/test-logo.jpg" I changed the master2 code to simply "test-logo.jpg" and to further make sure that this new master page is working throughout the sub-site, I changed the header of it from Logo Test Site to Master 2. I then made this master page the new default of the sub-site. To see this code in Designer, look at image below:

[image: Screenshot 5]

To make sure all works, I logged in as admin and went to Lisa's library to see if logo still displays for me (the admin) and if header changed - it does. See image below:

[image: Screenshot 6]

At this point, you would think that if I log out as admin, then log back in as Lisa, and keeping in mind that I changed the logo path to recognize the one on the sub-site and not in the _layouts folder, you'd think the logo would display for Lisa. Does it? No, it does not. See image below:

[image: Screenshot 7]

Then, for one final good measure, I simply right-clicked on the browser displaying this library to view the source code. As you'll see below, the code is pointing to the correct logo! Then, if it is, why isn't it displaying when Lisa views her library? See below:

[image: Screenshot 8]

So, that's where I'm at and I'm hoping someone knows why this is and what I need to do to fix it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first and foremost, check to see if that image is checked out. If it's checked out, you'll need to check it in, and probably publish it, for non-administrators to be able to see the image.

If it's not checked out, take a look at the security around the library where that image is stored and make sure that your normal users can view the items in that library; if they don't have access to the library and its contents, the image will be trimmed out by SharePoint's security model.

Answer (score 1):

In the past we have added a site logo to the /TEMPLATE/LAYOUTS directory in the 12 Hive.

This way every site will have access to the logo using: /_layouts/logo.jpg and site permissions will not get in the way.

Alternatively, you create an admin site, giving all authenticated users read access to the site and library.